# PRO*C Execution time of Query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-pro-c

**I am new to PRO*C** and when i execute a query, basic question comes on my mind is, how to get the Execution time?

**The option that comes on my mind to print the TIMESTAMP before and AFTER of Query. but, there will definitely be a better option than this, which i might have missed.**

Example:

```
printf("BEFORE %s", ctime(&my_time)); 

EXEC SQL SELECT dname, deptno 
FROM dept 
WHERE deptno IN (SELECT deptno FROM emp); 

printf("AFTER %s", ctime(&my_time));
```

Does PRO*C has any inbuilt option to get **the Execution Time of the Query**? I tried a lot but i was not able to get information related to it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way of Finding the Execution Time of QUERY. HERE IS THE QUERY

```
DECLARE
  curr_time1 DATE := SYSDATE;
  curr_time2 NUMBER := dbms_utility.get_time;
  L_VAR VARCHAR2(2);
BEGIN
  SELECT 1 INTO L_VAR FROM DUAL;
  dbms_output.put_Line ('Elapsed Time = '||(dbms_utility.get_time - curr_time2));
END;
/
```